# Flutter: My Android Emulator won't connect to firebase services

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with my app recently. I'm running my app on windows in a android emulator: SDK API 33.
Everything was working fine until yesterday. When i was in my HomeScreen my Firebase Firestore widgets weren't loading anymore, so i was wiping the data from my emulator.
Now i'm stuck at my Auth-Screen; when i want to login with my account i'm only getting this debug message when I'm pressing the login button:

`[ +873 ms] W/System( 7190): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.`

When i'm rebuilding the app i'm getting the message:

`W/FIAM.Headless( 7190): Service fetch error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 29.807599400s.`

Comment: Can you please check if it works on real device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727665/w-system-ignoring-header-x-firebase-locale-because-its-value-was-null)

Comment: @LucasTomic Hey, unfortunaly no. My emulator can connect to websites or google but not with my emulation device

Comment: @AhmadRaza Hello, on my real device it works. Cheers!

Comment: I have provided an answer below.please check

Answer (score 2):

The message "Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null." is just a warning and does not indicate a problem with your app or Firebase services.

Usual cause of this issue are Email/Password Sign-in method being disabled in the Firebase console and the Android emulator not being set up properly.

check these similar cases for more information:

- [Firebase Authentication Ignoring Header X-Firebase-Locale was
  null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73654264/flutter-firebase-authentication-ignoring-header-x-firebase-locale-because-its-va)
- [flutter Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value
  was null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68768127/flutter-ignoring-header-x-firebase-locale-because-its-value-was-null)
- [Firebase Cloud Function with Firestore returning "Deadline
  Exceeded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655344/firebase-cloud-function-with-firestore-returning-deadline-exceeded)

Also try  `flutter clean` command to delete any temporary files that may be causing problems. Then, rebuild and run your app.If you are still facing the issue , I have found this  [issue tracker raised](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236299915)  for a similar issue which is still open. you can report there or you can raise new raise issue at [github](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs).